# Calculator Using Enum

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

Hi so I am trying create a simple calculator using enum in my code to access the operators that the user will theoretically input.  The problem and the setup is in the image below.  However I cannot understand why this code will not work. Can anyone lead me in the right direction?  I don't need the actual solution but just a push towards it.

[image: task description]

This is the code I have so far.

```
enum MathOperator
{
    Add,
    Subtract,
    Multiply,
    Divide,
};

    public double Test5(double num1, double num2, MathOperator op)
    {
        double num3;

     switch (op)
        {
            case MathOperator.Add:
                num3 = num1 + num2;
                return num3;
            case MathOperator.Subtract:
                num3 = num1 - num2;
                return num3;
            case MathOperator.Multiply:
                num3 = num1 * num2;
                return num3;
            case MathOperator.Divide:
                num3 = num1 / num2;
                return num3;
        };
```

I have tried putting the enum within the body of the code, leaving out public before the enum, using switch (MathOperator) and more but I cannot seem to get it to even remotely work.

There are 3 errors:

> CS0535 - 'Submission' does not implement interface member Tests.Test5
>   (double, double, MatheOperator)
>
> CS0161 - Submission.Test5(double,double, Submission.MathOperator): not
>   all code paths return a value
>
> CS0051 - inconsisten accessibility: parameter type
>   'Submission.MathOperator is less accessible than method
>   Submission.Test5(double,double, Submission.MathOperator).

Comment: What do you mean by "will not work"? What errors / problems are you seeing?

Comment: By quickly looking at it, it should work. Have you tried just calling this method with hard coded parameters? Like Console.WriteLine(Test5(10, 10, MathOperator.Add)); ?

Comment: you're missing a default in the swtich or an extra return outside of the switch in case the enum you get is not any of these 4 cases.

Comment: So when I run it like this I get 3 errors.  The first error CS0535 - 'Submission' does not implement interface member Tests.Test5 (double, double, MatheOperator), CS0161 - Submission.Test5(double,double, Submission.MathOperator): not all code paths return a value, and error CS0051 - inconsisten accessibility: parameter type 'Submission.MathOperator is less accessible than method Submission.Test5(double,double, Submission.MathOperator).

Comment: Please add those error messages to your question. They are an essential piece of information.

Comment: Sorry about that will do from now on.

Comment: Also please paste all relevant code so that we get a working example, I see at least 1 missing curly bracket. Additionnaly I don't think there's any use of adding a semicolon after a curly bracket.

Comment: I don't know about `CS0535`, but [Krishna's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116034/2550406) effectively addresses the other two errors I think.

Comment: Do you implement from an interface that has a typo? 'MatheOperator'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking but your console application should look like this

```
class Program
{
    //add public for the error: inconsist accessibility bla bla..
    public enum MathOperator { Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide, }; 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Test5(10, 10, MathOperator.Add));
    }

    public static double Test5(double num1, double num2, MathOperator op)
    {
        double num3;

        switch (op)
        {
            case MathOperator.Add:
                num3 = num1 + num2;
                return num3;
            case MathOperator.Subtract:
                num3 = num1 - num2;
                return num3;
            case MathOperator.Multiply:
                num3 = num1 * num2;
                return num3;
            case MathOperator.Divide:
                num3 = num1 / num2;
                return num3;
           //add default switch case for error: not all code paths return a value  bla bla..
            default:
                return 0;
        };

    }
}
```